# Multiple value selection and optional filter in SSRS 2005 report

Tags: wildcard, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I had done a fair share of research before asking this here.
Firstly, i would like to create a drop-down filter @accessVar with the ability to select multiple values. It would be easy if not due to my special requirement. My dataset statement is:

```
SELECT PASS_M, ENTRY_DT, EXIT_DT, WORKED_HRS, ACCESS_LOCATION_X, IC_N, COMPANY_M,           CONSECUTIVE_D 
FROM TEMP_TARGET
WHERE (CONSECUTIVE_D >= @consecDays) AND (ENTRY_DT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND
(ACCESS_LOCATION_X LIKE @accessVar) AND
(IC_N LIKE @icVAr)
```

However i need to make use the %wildcard for @accessVar(e.g 'BT%') hence i am unable to use the operator IN. What can i do? I am using SSRS2005. Please advice me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Filter at the Data Set properties. Before that you need to remove the `(ACCESS_LOCATION_X LIKE @accessVar)` from your data set query.

set the expression as follows[Modify your parameter name].

```
=ACCESS_LOCATION_X Like "*"+Parameters!param.Value+"*"
```

Then configure the Dataset properties Filter tab as follows.

[image]

After that you can run your report. Following screenshot searches for "en" word in the report data set and returns the result set.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi i got an error after trying: The FilterExpression expression for the data set 'DataSpurce1' contains an error: [BC30452] Operator 'Like' is not defined for types 'Microsoft.ReportingService.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field' and 'Object'" And i am using SSRS 2005. My filter properties inside dataset is different. I do have a dropdown to select boolean. Btw thanks for ur effot and help

Comment: Can you post your expression used in the filter section?

Comment: =Fields!ACCESS_LOCATION_X Like "*" + Parameters!accessVar.Value + "*" after entering this expression i click ok and for operator i choose equal and for value i enter True. I do not have a place to select the boolean
i include the asteris inside "", but it just wont display in stackoverflow

Comment: any other suggestions? please need this urgently

Comment: @10e5x can you use stored procedures?