# Making a filter parameter optional

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am using SSRS 2005. I created a report parameter named icVar. What should i do to allow this filter to be optional. Meaning if user enter something into the textbox, will display result according to what is entered but if nothing is entered it will just treat it to display all. This is the query in my dataset.

```
SELECT PASS_M, ENTRY_DT, EXIT_DT, WORKED_HRS, ACCESS_LOCATION_X, IC_N, COMPANY_M,  
CONSECUTIVE_D
FROM TEMP_TARGET
WHERE (CONSECUTIVE_D >= @consecDays) AND (ENTRY_DT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) AND
(ACCESS_LOCATION_X LIKE @accessVar) AND
(IC_N LIKE @icVAr)
```

I am making use of the wildcard % for my icVar. So if user input S123 for that filter the report will display result where IC_N values starting with S123... However when nothing is entered for that filter, do not force the user to input anything. It shall show IC_N Like %(means all) if nothing is entered.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use expression evaluation short-circuiting - test for Null first and only if it is not Null does the next part of the expression evaluate, testing for `LIKE` (see the condition on the last line):

```
SELECT PASS_M, ENTRY_DT, EXIT_DT, WORKED_HRS, ACCESS_LOCATION_X, IC_N, COMPANY_M, CONSECUTIVE_D
FROM TEMP_TARGET
WHERE (CONSECUTIVE_D >= @consecDays) 
AND (ENTRY_DT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) 
AND (ACCESS_LOCATION_X LIKE @accessVar) 
AND ((@icVar IS NULL) OR (IC_N LIKE @icVAr))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can u show me the whole where statement if i want to say if icVar is null, it is Where IC_N like '%' else IC_N LIKE icVar. i think what u suggest is somewhat similar but i do not know how to test ur solution and IC_N does not have null values.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the full SQL - basically you are only testing IC_N when the parameter is not null

Comment: Thanks, it works. Thanks for the solution, i need that urgently and ur solution make it on time. Do you mind see if u can help me with this qns. U might be able to help.
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857201/multiple-value-selection-and-optional-filter-in-ssrs-2005-report[link]

Comment: I'm using a similar solution for my own project. Doesn't this defeat the purpose of SSRS report filters though since it will require another query instead of reusing the dataset?

Comment: It doesn't require another dataset, this SQL is used on the main dataset. I don't think the OP is using shared datasets or SSRS report filters, so you can just use SQL to do the heavy lifting of selecting the data rather than filtering it at the report level.