# Multi-value optional filters with the usage of wildcard in SSRS 2005

Tags: filter, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have asked this question before but there are no solution to it. I have created a multivalue filter with the following data-set.

```
SELECT PASS_M, ENTRY_DT, EXIT_DT, WORKED_HRS, ACCESS_LOCATION_X, IC_N, COMPANY_M,  CONSECUTIVE_D 
FROM TEMP_TARGET
WHERE (CONSECUTIVE_D >= @consecDays) AND (ENTRY_DT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)               AND
(ACCESS_LOCATION_X LIKE @accessVar) AND
(IC_N LIKE @icVAr)
```

It would be relatively easy if the value of my `accessVar` does not use wildcard but i needed that. So there will be 5 values possible in `accessVar`:

```
%(means all), 'At%', 'Bet%', 'Co%' and 'Dea%'
```

I am unable to use In operator with wildcard. Secondly, can i make this kind of dropdown filters optional? if nth is selected, just query all.

What other options do i have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a filter parameter optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871372/making-a-filter-parameter-optional). Please don't repost a *third* time.

Comment: Ok sure. However i dk what to do to bump my prev post. I got no solution to my prev post. The one that helped me halfway stopped replying so i trying my luck the second time. I promise i wont post similar qns again. Sry

Comment: A hint: when you click the green check on an answer, as you did, you indicate that you're satisfied with that answer. That will naturally inhibit further answers. Don't accept an answer until you're reasonably confident that it solves your problem.

Comment: Think u mistaken the similar qns that i post. Think my problems are too similar. This is the same qns to [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857201/multiple-value-selection-and-optional-filter-in-ssrs-2005-report

Comment: Ok got it, i will bear that in mind. Sry. So should i delete the old post or wait for some1 to reply over there too?

Comment: It'd be better for the community to consolidate the questions, but I don't think it matters a ton, 10e5x.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use LIKE and multi-value parameters together, which isn't going to work. However, Reporting Services gives us the ability to do almost anything we want. The solution is to use custom code and expressions. First, we change your SQL statement into an expression, like so:

```
="SELECT PASS_M, ENTRY_DT, EXIT_DT, WORKED_HRS, ACCESS_LOCATION_X, IC_N, "
&"COMPANY_M, CONSECUTIVE_D "
&"FROM TEMP_TARGET "
&"WHERE (CONSECUTIVE_D >= @consecDays) "
&"AND (ENTRY_DT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) "
&"AND ((@accessvar IS NULL) OR (ACCESS_LOCATION_X LIKE @accessVar)) "
&"AND ((@icVar IS NULL) OR (IC_N LIKE @icVAr)) "
```

So now the SQL statement is actually a string expression that will evaluate to a SQL expression which will execute.

Next we need to convert your multi-value parameter into a series of `LIKE` statements, which we can do with custom code. Add the following custom code to your report (right-click report, select Properties and click the Code tab):

```
Function AccessLocations (ByVal parameter As Parameter) AS String
  Dim Result As String
  If parameter.IsMultiValue then
    Result = "AND ( " 
    For i as integer = 0 to parameter.Count-1 
      Result = Result + "(ACCESS_LOCATION LIKE '" + CStr(parameter.Value(i)) + "') OR "  
    Next 
    Result = Left(Result, Result.Length - 3) +") "
  Else 
    Result = "AND (ACCESS_LOCATION LIKE '" + CStr(parameter.Value) + "') "
  End If 

  Return Result
End Function
```

Then we call this function as part of the SQL statement:

```
Code.AccessLocations(Parameters!accessvar)
```

So your full SQL is:

```
="SELECT PASS_M, ENTRY_DT, EXIT_DT, WORKED_HRS, ACCESS_LOCATION_X, IC_N, "
&"COMPANY_M, CONSECUTIVE_D "
&"FROM TEMP_TARGET "
&"WHERE (CONSECUTIVE_D >= @consecDays) "
&"AND (ENTRY_DT BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate) "
& Code.AccessLocations(Parameters!accessvar)
&"AND ((@icVar IS NULL) OR (IC_N LIKE @icVAr)) "
```

If your parameter has the `%` wildcard in it then this will work; otherwise add the wildcard to the function.

Comment: I did try apply your solution before even asking, but it just keep prompts me "An error occured during local report processing. Query execution failed for data set 'DataSource1'. Incorrect syntax near ','." And i did try out different variations.

Comment: I think i uds where i go wrong already, but i got no solution to that. I have this error maybe becuz when i select more then one, for e.g At and Bet, the program will query At%, Bet%. Therefore an error?

Comment: Please see what u can do Chris.

Comment: Yes, that would be the error - you aren't going to be able to use a multi-value parameter in a LIKE clause.

Comment: erm amybe i am not clear in asking but thats what i am asking from the start of this qns... any advice? alternative? Thanks for helping.

Comment: some1 helped me halfway. maybe u can take a look too? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857201/multiple-value-selection-and-optional-filter-in-ssrs-2005-report?lq=1

Comment: That won't work with a multi-value parameter - I have a solution that I am posting now

Comment: Thanks Chris, may u teach me how to add the expression as sql? When i edit my dataset, no options fr me to add expression. Or do i just copy ='SELECT...... ))" inside the sql editor?

Comment: Yes, you just put the ="SELECT... " in where you would normally write SQL. The SQL statement is actually a string expression so you can manipulate it by generating your own string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21238/discussion-between-10e5x-and-chris-latta)